# Load an external text. Works on my computer, but not on app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an app for Air 3.8 on Flash CS6. When I click on info_btn, the programm load an external textfile (here test.txt) and shows it in my dynamic text field (here info_txt). 
It works when I CRTL+Enter, but not on my android device when I test the .apk file I created. I'm sure the reason is that the test.txt is not compiled in the apk, but I don't know how to change that. If you guys can help, it would be great.

Here is my code, if it can help:

```
var fl_TextLoader_3:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var fl_TextURLRequest_3:URLRequest = new URLRequest("textes/test.txt");

fl_TextLoader_3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fl_CompleteHandler_3);

function fl_CompleteHandler_3(event:Event):void
{
var textData:String = new String(fl_TextLoader_3.data);
info_txt.text = textData;
}

info_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_infotxt);
function fl_infotxt(Event:MouseEvent):void {
fl_TextLoader_3.load(fl_TextURLRequest_3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually mobile AIR projects will have an `assets` folder -- they do in Flash Builder and Flash Develop IDEs, so I assume CS6 has something similar.

The assets folder is where images and app icons go that will be delivered in the .apk.  You can put any files and folders you want in there, including your text files.  To package your text file into the .apk, you could create a `assets/textes` folder and put your `test.txt` in it.

Then the URL you would need in your code would be:

```
var fl_TextURLRequest_3:URLRequest = new URLRequest("assets/textes/test.txt");
```

Comment: it works. couldn't find the asset folder so i created it, I put my textes folder in it, and went to the air 3.1 parameters, and added it. Thank you very much Jeff:)

Comment: Excellent, glad you found the AIR parameters - that was the difficult part I wasn't quite sure how to explain.  Note that AIR 3.1 is pretty far out of date.  If you're going to target iOS 7, you need to use AIR 4.0 or later.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm using air 3.8. I'll look for newer version. Thanks :)